# Subversion / Tortoise / asp.net - Ignore and Non-versioned

Tags: asp.net, svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

I'm probably reading too much into ignore, but other than not showing up in the list when you commit, are there any other feature/benefits associated with ignoring a file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It also doesn't clutter your `svn status` list. But anyway, not commiting files to the repo that don't need to be versioned (e.g. because they are created by the application, or they are settings files) is a pretty useful feature by itself, I'd think.

Comment: I agree and I started adding files to the ignore list since I'm starting to accumulate alot of files.

But assuming that a non-versioned file doesn't get to the repo and you don't mind doing a "turn a blind eye manual ignore" and you have few files to ignore, I don't see much difference between leaving a file un-versioned vs adding it to ignore, but I definitely see the merits/benefits when you have alot of files to ignore.

Anyways, just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something.

Answer (score 0):

files to ignore:

1. files generated during a build (local properties, byte code, etc)
2. files generated during runtime (log files)
3. svn meta files

imagine NOT being able to ignore all of this